# Check out file from VS2010 VsPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, vsix, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I have a VS2010 VsPackage that implements an editor for a certain XML based file format.

Currently I'm displaying an error in case the file is read-only. I would like to check if the file is under source code control before editing and offer to check out the file or cancel the edit operation.

How can I do this from my extension package code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here:
[Invoking standard "File changed outside Visual Studio" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413086/invoking-standard-file-changed-outside-visual-studio-dialog/10667845#10667845)

In particular, `IVsQueryEditQuerySave2` may work for you.